# KVM-Host lost connection to Storage

Tags: linux, networking, virtualization, kvm-virtualization, iscsi

I would really appreciate some advice on how to fix this. I have a Debian KVM-Host with 9 Debian VMS running on it. The virtual machines are running on my little Storage via iSCSI.

Now, my switch just temporarily lost power and with it the connection broke off from Host to storage. Now I have a host full of VMS that are in paused mode because they can't deal with that sudden interruption.

I have a feeling that I may have corrupted the disks of all my VMs. Would someone of you know if there is still hope for the VMs to restore themselves?

**Edit:** I got the connection to the iSCSI target active again by saving the VMs' state and rebooting the host. The OSs on the disks are still crashed. Would you know if it is save to hard-reboot them or is there an other way of resolving that state? They are all formated with EXT4.

Comment: If the storage is online again, you ought to be able to just resume the guests.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Edit:** Even after the switch got power again and the storage was available, the VM's were still in an unresponsive crashed state. They did not react to any input whatsoever forcing me to do a hard-reset one by one, relying on the filesystem journaling to repair the damage. I was lucky it worked and nothing borked.

As far as I understand, I got lucky there as fsck only removes/repairs faulty references without keeping data integrity in mind. The MySQL Server seems to be working fine but if everything is still in place, thats another question. I'd appreciate some coments on how I could have handled that problem better (aside from clustering, backuping more frequently and percausions like that).

Comment: you should have simply restored the iscsi link and unpaused the VMs, almost certainly no harm would have been done

Comment: Yeah, that would have been my first guess too. I updated the post to clear up that misunderstanding.

Comment: The update does not clear anything up. You "fixed" the iscsi connection by rebooting the host. What you should have done is restore the iscsi sessions without a reboot, verified the LUNs are accessible and resumed the VMs. No restart needed, no data loss would have happened

Answer (score 4):

Modern OS and filesystem are much more resilient against corruption, and the same can be said for MySQL (especially when used with InnoDB tables).

Basically, anything written to disk with `sync/fsync` semantic should be crash-safe, as the writes will not return until the data are on stable storage. Moreover, InnoDB uses internal journaling to be sure no partial record are written.

In short, while minor data loss can sometime happen, I would be very surprised if a modern (2.6.33+) Linux installation become completely wrong after a crash.

Comment: Thank you for that few behind the scene. I completely forgot about database logfiles. I'm way out of my comfort zone here but I would like to explore this a bit further. That data is stored on stable storage does not mean that the data is still usable by the OS/Application no?  I mean, assuming that all developers know that fsync exists and are using it consistently throughout their applications, fsync can't know whether an application is flushing arbitrarily or because it's finished and is preparing to close the stream. Or am I looking at it wrong?

Comment: Correct fsync use implies applications must use or at proper boundaries, for example at each full record write/flush. Fsync Can only guarantee that something landed on stable storage, but it is applucation's duty to keep track of what the written data are logically grouped/validated. This is generally achieved by application-level journaling/doublewrite.

Answer (score 2):

Qemu takes VMs into pause on io errors by design, so that you will avoid corrupt disks. All you have to do is restore the iscsi connections and run/unpause the VMs

Comment: Hi, yeah I thought so too, but this did infact not work. The iSCSI connection was active and the VMs were still crashed and did not respond to any keyboard input whatsoever. Hence the crowbar-approach with VMs.

Comment: Did you try to resume the paused VMs, after making sure the storage is accessible?